# Summing up the weight of all edges to a node in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to sum up the weight of all edges connected to a node and use it as the node score? The sum would be an array where than I would need to order them from the highest node with more edges to the lowest one.
By the way I am using force layout in D3.

Thank you.

So far:

```
var sum=[]
            edges.style("stroke", function(d, i) {

                if ((d.source.name == node_name)  ||  (d.target.name == node_name))

                {   dataset.nodes.push(function(d){
                    //console.log(d.name)
                    return {sum:d.name}});

                    sum+= d.weight;
                    //console.log(d3.max(sum))
                    return  "#000"}
                else
                {
                    return "#ccc"}

            });

        })
```

Comment: I think you should post a bit more of your code. maybe as jsfiddle?
With the current code we can't see what `dataset` or `node_name` actually are.

Comment: `sum = []` is turning the sum into an array. You then string append d.weight to it on each node. This is unlikely to do what you want. Why not start with `sum=0`, and take it from there?

Comment: @jhinzmann this is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/qguk1gqu/ even that the graph it's not showing because of not referencing the d3.

Comment: Is there a reason for calculating the sum on click?
Maybe it would be easier to calculate the score for each node before the graph is rendered.
Also without the `assignments.json` it's hard to know what's going on there...

Comment: Did my answer help you? Or is there still some problem to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're loading your data with `d3.json`, one approach would be to calculate the score directly after the data is loaded and not on click like in your fiddle.
If your data is formatted like [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045), then the following code stores the score of each node as `score` attribute on the node.
Maybe you have to adjust the attribute names `nodes`, `links`, `source`, `target`, `score` and `value` according to your dataset.

```
d3.json("assignments.json", function(error, graph) {
  graph.nodes = graph.nodes.map(function(node, index){
    node.score = graph.links
      .filter(function(d){
        return (d.source === index || d.target === index);
      })
      .map(function(d){
        return d.value;
      })
      .reduce(function(prev, curr){
        return prev + curr;
      },0);
    return node;
  });
/**
 * init force here
 */
});
```